# Adjusting Eclipse console size

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, how do you adjust the maximum lines in the console window? My program outputs 2000 lines of numbers and Eclipse truncates it so therefore I am missing some numbers.

It says here:

http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/run-debug/ref-console.htm

that it's under `run/debug > console`, but I don't see that option anywhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I increase the capacity of the Eclipse output console?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828255/how-do-i-increase-the-capacity-of-the-eclipse-output-console)

Comment: Have to post an answer due to reputation limit. I was running a program that prints out a lot of lines(think trillions) to make sure it was running. Setting the console limit to unlimited was actually slowing the program down as the console kept eating memory up. Just a heads up if you run into very large programs like that.

Answer (score 197, accepted):

In `Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > Console`, there's a checkbox "Limit console output" and a text field for entering the buffer size of the console.

Have never changed those settings myself but sounds like this could be what you are looking for. I am using Eclipse 3.3.2.

Comment: #lifehack you can search the preferences with the string "console" to IMO more easily get to the setting

Comment: Also, includes the console width setting.

Answer (score 33):

`Right click on the console > Preferences > Console buffer size`

If you don't want any limit, uncheck the "Limit console output" checkbox.

Mine is currently set to 800000, which is enough.

Comment: That said, I would strongly recommend setting a high limit rather than no limit at all. If you forget to clean your console, you can run Eclipse out of heap space, IIRC.

Comment: In Eclipse Indigo, there is no Window -> Preferences. Right click on the text view of the console to bring up menu which has Preferences.

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar problem with my c++ build console. This is set in Preferences->C/C++->Build->Console

Answer (score 6):

Same thing I also forgot every time.
Step 1: form toolbar click on 'window' then 'preference' 
step 2: go'run/Debug' form lift side of preference window and select 'console' 
step 3: In right side of windows increase the size of 'Console buffer size(characters)'
step 4: click ok to exit
**[window -->preference -->run/Debug -->console -->*Console buffer size(characters)*]**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Later versions of eclipse should have it under Eclipse > Preferences > Run/Debug > Console. Then uncheck the "Limit console output" box.