# How do I increase the capacity of the Eclipse output console?

Tags: eclipse, console

Even with the "scroll lock" option enabled for the Eclipse console, eventually it overfills and starts auto-scrolling on me.

Is there some way of increasing the capacity of the console so that it stores more lines? I wasn't able to find the option.

Comment: Thank you, all. I kept looking under general and under Java, didn't think that this would be part of Run/Debug. My bad.

Comment: one thing i love about the pref window on eclipse, you can just type in a search in the top left , i can never remember where this stuff is buried, but if you type console , you can see (at least with my install CDT,galileo) that there is a limit setting for the build console as well as the run console as well as the CVS console:)

Comment: @iondiode: That's right. The funny thing is, I looked for such a search window and didn't see it. Then I realized that I am so used to the mac and having it on the top-right, that I never noticed the text box above the tree on the left!

Comment: possible duplicate of [adjusting eclipse console size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600653/adjusting-eclipse-console-size)

Answer (score 637, accepted):

Under `Window > Preferences`, go to the `Run/Debug > Console` section, then you should see an option "Limit console output." You can uncheck this or change the number in the "Console buffer size (characters)" text box below.

(This is in Galileo, Helios CDT, Kepler, Juno, Luna, Mars, Neon, Oxygen and 2018-09)

Comment: I can't believe this is my highest voted answer on SO. I memorised the C standard for nothing.

Comment: Caution: Deactivating this option is unfortunately very buggy. Deactivating the limit causes all kinds of strange behaviour (Juno) with regard to memory. I would advise against it.

Comment: @detly That option is there in Helios too

Comment: If you do disable the limit, you are probably having memory problems because you never clear your console. Click the paper with the grey X on it once and a while.

Comment: Is there any drawback ?

Comment: @detly, the path in Preferences has remained exactly the same for Oxygen as well.

Comment: @mapto Woohoo, my one-answer reputation farm continues!

Comment: Why not? It is still useful, Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't work for CDT users. See the other answer below.

Comment: `Cmd + ,` for mac

Answer (score 50):

Open the Windows > Preferences menu.

Expand the Run/Debug > Console preferences.

Set the `Console buffer size (characters)` to something much bigger. `2147383647` / ~2GB is the upper limit (or `1000000` / ~1MB in older releases). Or just uncheck the `Limit console output`.

Comment: Upper limit is now 2147383647, about 2GB, as of Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a) Build id: 20171005-1200.

Answer (score 24):

For **CDT** users / **C/C++ build**, also adjust the setting

in Window > Preferences

under C/C++ > Build > Console (!)

(This time in number of lines.)

This also affects the "CDT Global Build Console".

Answer (score 16):

**Alternative**

If your console is not empty, **right click** on the **Console area** > **Preferences...** > change the value for the **Console buffer size (characters)** (recommended) or uncheck the **Limit console output** (not recommended):

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is currently the best answer because the menu structure (i.e. Window/Preferences) has changed since the date the question was answered

Answer (score 9):

On the MAC OS X 10.9.5 and Eclipse Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1), its not found under the Window menu, but instead under: Eclipse > Preferences > Run/Debug > Console.

Answer (score 3):

Window > Preferences, go to the Run/Debug > Console section >> "Limit console output.>>Console buffer size(characters):"
(This option can be seen in Eclipse Indigo ,but it limits buffer size at 1,000,000 )

Comment: Or click `Cmd + ,`

Answer (score 3):

Under Window > Preferences, go to the Run/Debug > Console section, then you should see an option "Limit console output." You can unchecked this or change the number in the "Console buffer size (characters)" text box below. Do Unchecked.

This is for the Eclipse like Galileo, Kepler, Juno, Luna, Mars and Helios.

Answer (score 2):

> Please go through the below guidelines. Do the changes accordingly.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For C++ users, to increase the Build console output size see [here](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/run-debug/ref-console.htm)

ie Windows > Preference > C/C++ > Build > Console

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has limit of 32000 characters per line. If you have, for example JSONObject, which you want to log into console, you won't succeed. You can't handle this with the checkbox. Tested