# Eclipse CDT Build Console output not displaying entire compiler output

Tags: c++, console, eclipse-cdt

When building and debugging a large C++ program, the output to the console is so large that the console cuts off the start of the output. This is particularly annoying as the first error outputted by the compiler is often the most important for debugging purposes.

---

EDIT:
So the question is: How do I view the entire console output?

Comment: Good point, I'll edit to make it clear what the question was.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two ways to get around this:

1. Change how many lines the console is limited to. Go to Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Console, then change "Limit console output (number of lines):" to a number higher than the default 500.
2. Make the console output save to a file, which doesn't have a predefined line limit. Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Logging, then change the location of the Log file location to somewhere you can easily access it. I'd advise not opening the file in Window's default text editor as it loses any helpful formatting, instead eclipse's text editor works well.