# In java, System.out.print() won't print characters after certain limit

Tags: java

I have the following code

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int []n= new int[6000];

    for(int i=0;i<6000;i++){
        n[i]=1;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<6000;i++){
        System.out.print(n[i]);
    }



}
```

There is no output in the console. However if I decrease the limit for the loop like ,

```
  for(int i=0;i<3000;i++){
        System.out.print(n[i]);
    }
```

Now I can see the output. It looks like System.out.print() only prints if all the numbers fit in a single line.

Now how can I print all the numbers which fit in a single line and later go to the next line and print rest of them?

Comment: Are you running your code from an IDE (if so, which one ?), or from command line ?

Comment: Assuming you're using Eclipse, this is a duplicate of [Eclipse console doesn't show the whole output](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9312855/5221149), and it's a known bug in Eclipse.

Comment: Possibly related: [Character limit for System.out.println() in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8912202/4539511)

Comment: @Berger I'm using Eclipse.

Comment: There is no limit on the Java side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse console doesn't show the whole output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312855/eclipse-console-doesnt-show-the-whole-output)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question "how can I print all the numbers which fit in a single line and later go to the next line" :

Simply start a new row after every `lineLength` prints:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[]n= new int[6000];
        Arrays.fill(n, 1);

        int lineLength = 80;
        int timesPrinted = 0;

        for (int element : n) {

            System.out.print(element);

            if(timesPrinted == lineLength) {
                System.out.print("\n");
                timesPrinted = 0;
            }else {
                timesPrinted++;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: The problem is I want to use the entire line and then go the next line.

Comment: What is "entire line" ?  Eclipse will not print it to consul. You can print it to file