# Jsoup doesn't parse entire html document

Tags: parsing, html-parsing, jsoup

I'm trying to fetch a whole bunch of links from a website using Jsoup. My Plan was to fetch the entire html from the url and extract the links later. However only a portion of the entire html code is fetched.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    System.out.println("parsing test");

    try {

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://mangafox.com/manga").get();
        System.out.print(doc);

    } catch (Exception e) {}

}
```

When I compare the the printout to the original html code in the browser, seems like it starts somewhere in the middle at letter m and end shortly after around letter o.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else ends up here...

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
    .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0")
    .maxBodySize(0)
    .timeout(600000)
    .get();
```

via - http://jmchung.github.io/blog/2013/10/25/how-to-solve-jsoup-does-not-get-complete-html-document/

Comment: This code can't parse site section which is loaded by javascript dynamically.

Comment: "In case anyone else ends up here" and doesn't like dead links: the context help of `maxBodySize()` mentions a default limit of 2MB. So setting it to `0` indeed lifts the limit, but you should still use something like "current length * 2" to be on the safe side and still don't have to watch the computer explode...

Answer (score 0):

It happens because there are character limit for `System.out.print` (at least in eclipse). Html page is bigger than that limit and that is why you don't see whole document in console.

You can increase console buffer size [like it describes here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912202/character-limit-for-system-out-println-in-java)

Or print your `html` to file like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
   try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://mangafox.com/manga").get();
        //System.out.print(doc);

        //write to document
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("output.txt");
        out.print(doc.toString());
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {}

}
```

Comment: well it starts to print out more now, but still a big portion is missing from the original html code.