# Server can't parse something in ajax post parameter, what is causing this?

Tags: java, ajax, servlets, form-data

I'm making an ajax post request, and i can see the value is being passed in the headers on the client side.

However on the server side the value received is blank? The server seems to be choking on something in the value when it tries to parse it. Because if i use encodeURIComponent it works fine. What is causing this behaviour?

```
<script>

    //var body = getDataFromTheEditor(); //doesn't work
    //var body = JSON.stringify(getDataFromTheEditor()); //doesn't work
    var body = encodeURIComponent(getDataFromTheEditor()); //works but don't want to do this...

    var params = {body: body};
    $.post("../../../../CommitEdit", $.param(params));

</script>
```

Servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String body = request.getParameter("body");
    System.out.println(body); //blank if i pass it normally :(

}
```

I've copied the formdata directly from the header as it is being passed (so there's something in here which the server doesn't like apparently):

[pastebin - unparsed formdata](https://pastebin.com/dv2KnhWe)

[pastebin - parsed formdata](https://pastebin.com/MuF4b62x)

Relevant request headers:

```
Content-Length: 64488
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: `System.out.println(body);` gives you a blank (empty String) or `null`?

Comment: blank value is being passed

Comment: No repo. I'm getting the full text from the server side without encoding.

Comment: hmm looks like i am getting something, but the string is cut off and there's an abnormally long amount of blank space before it (so it looked like it was just blank) but had to scroll horizontally. Are you getting that?

Comment: Yeah there's a blank space in front of the text. I can confirm that. But I got from `<p>` to `</p>`. I didn't check the middle part though.

Comment: Wrap the text in your output console, if possible. Then you can view the full output.

Comment: what do you mean exactly by wrapping the text in system.out ?

Comment: and what IDE are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because the string was too long. Apparently the console in Eclipse has a character limit. Which is why i was seeing a blank value. This question here helped solve the issue:

[Character limit for System.out.println() in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912202/character-limit-for-system-out-println-in-java)

The solution is to:

> 1. Go to Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > Console
> 2. Uncheck "Limit Console Output" (Alternatively you can increase the Console buffer size.)

Answer (score 0):

It maybe caused because of some security rules in the web server settings. 
You can decode your data in Java using this:

```
String res= java.net.URLDecoder.decode(body, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Yes i know how to decode the encoded string, but i'm interested in knowing why this is happening. And why i can't just pass it without encoding it like any other string.