# Output broken in eclipse java console

Tags: java, eclipse, console, output, println

I have an array of all 100000 natural numbers(1 ... 100000). I sorted it and printed the sorted array to the console but the console didn't show all the numbers the numbers were from 84599 to 100000 only.

Comment: This means your console is only showing you the `100000 - 84599 = 15401` last lines of output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That has to do with the display buffer size of eclipse console

I would recommend looking at this question:

[How do I increase the capacity of the Eclipse output console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828255/how-do-i-increase-the-capacity-of-the-eclipse-output-console)

Answer (score 2):

Console has a text buffer, which is of finite size, and when it fills up, the old text is lost.

Make the buffer larger through Console Preferences.

Tip: type Ctrl-3 (⌘+3 on Mac), then `console`, to quickly access the Console Preferences without drilling down through the Eclipse Preferences tree.

Answer (score 1):

> Windows -> Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Console ->

Uncheck "Limit console output" to have unlimited console output