# Eclipse Console Output Limit

Tags: java, serialization, bufferedreader

I am using BufferReader to read log files from a game server. It does work but it just doesn't read the entire file just a small portion of it.

My code:

```
public ArrayList<String> readFile(File file){           
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file.getAbsolutePath())))
    {
        String sCurrentLine;
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            list.add(sCurrentLine);                     
        }
        return list;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null; 
}
```

The files that i try to read have the size between 0.5 MB - 1.5 MB. The server logs look like this but it has many more lines. Like 20000 lines. I am only getting like 1500 lines from it.

```
00:05:29 - Great_Zhupan_Uros_SRB <img=ico_spear> Wolfpack_SikiciArthasan 
00:05:32 - Teamhit: AE_Shemaforash hit AB_Artorius for 10 hp. 
00:05:32 - AE_Shemaforash <img=ico_axeone> AB_Artorius 
00:05:32 - AE_Shemaforash(20578) teamkilled AB_Artorius(1076080). 
00:05:41 - Great_Zhupan_Uros_SRB <img=ico_spear> IR_Fall3N~3nG3l 
00:05:46 - AE_Shemaforash <img=ico_axeone> Xodanrot
00:06:05 - *DEAD* [AE_Blivandefar] xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
00:06:05 - Wolfpack_Dennell has joined the game with ID: 1305305 
00:06:07 - Wolfpack_Dennell joined the server.
```

The log file starts at time 00:00:00 and ends at 23:59:59. When i start reading it, it only reads a small part of it like from 22:08:00 to 23:59:59. Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong? And if there are better solutions for this then i am all ears. Im using this data to convert them into statistics for players.

Comment: How do you "read" your logs? Do you open the file with some text editor or try to print the elements of the list? And by the way, didn't you want to have your BufferedReader set up inside the try block?

Comment: With what code do you establish how much was read? You should post that code.

Comment: @Byakuya This is how he "reads" his logs: `while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            list.add(sCurrentLine);                     
        }`. And yes, he *does* have his BufferedReader set up inside the try block.

Comment: This is how he adds them to the list. The point of my question was to get info about how does he know how much lines did he get.

Comment: @Byakuya: this is a try-with-resources statement.. :)

Comment: That I did not know, so I just asked. I believe we still do not know how does Tom know how many lines did he get.

Comment: @Byakuya I just a system.out.prntln  on each string ive put it that list. Compared the console output to the file i selected. I updated my OP with some additional data.

Comment: And you wouldn't by any chance rely on Eclipse/NetBeans Console window to count the lines? If yes, then there's your problem: the window has a maximum scrollback limit set to 1500 lines.

Comment: Console may not be able to print all the lines (the max amount may be limited). How about checking the size of your list?

Comment: oh seriously i feel stupid now

Comment: @Tom: I don't see anything wrong with codes for reading the file. Anyways, you can directly pass the file to the FileReader constructor. No need to get the absolute path from it.

Comment: anyways to increase that limit?

Comment: Do you really want to print more than a thousand lines for anyone to be of use?

Comment: @Tom: are you trying this on an IDE? If not, what is the OS?

Comment: List size says 16966 so thats good =) Im using eclipse OS is windows 8

Comment: I would recomment not printing it to screen at once. Ever. No one is going to read it, probably.

Comment: So in other words the BufferedReader *does* read the entire file and your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Was not the "size" of the log the problem?

Comment: Yes you are right. I didn't know there was a limit to the lines in the console Thanks everyone!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828255/how-do-i-increase-the-capacity-of-the-eclipse-output-console
Btw, @Byakuya is right.. there is no point of printing this all to console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complex answer appears to be:

1. The code for reading from the file is working fine.
2. If you store the lines read from the file in a list then probably the best way to check how many of them were read is to **check the size() of the list**.
3. Do not print huge amounts of information (like 1000+ lines, or actually even 100+...) to the console, as such amount is probably not to be read by anyone, ever.

Comment: Just to clarify point 3 is that i printed it to look how it looks and from that i know how to proceed futher to cut the string in pieces =)

Comment: For such purpose printing 5 or 10 elements from the list should be sufficient, I believe, and for sure easier to read through.