# Generating a random int in Java

Tags: java, random, numbers, range

I have this code that if it does is generate random numbers in a range that I choose. The problem I have is that if they see the line of for, I supposedly have to generate 10000 random numbers, but this only makes me 6668. If I put a less than that amount, the code works fine. What's going on? Eclipse has some sort of character limit?
Thank you very much!

Greetings!

```
import java.util.Random;
  public static final void main(String... aArgs){
log("Generating random integers in the range 1..10.");
    int START = 2000000 ;
int END =   8999999 ;
Random random = new Random();
for (int idx = 1; idx <= 10000; ++idx){
  showRandomInteger(START, END, random);
}

log("Done.");


}
private static void showRandomInteger(int aStart, int aEnd, Random aRandom){
if (aStart > aEnd) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Start cannot exceed End.");
    }
//get the range, casting to long to avoid overflow problems
long range = (long)aEnd - (long)aStart + 1;
// compute a fraction of the range, 0 <= frac < range
long fraction = (long)(range * aRandom.nextDouble());
int randomNumber =  (int)(fraction + aStart);    
log("351" + randomNumber);


}
 private static void log(String aMessage){
System.out.println(aMessage);
  }
}
```

Comment: Try increasing Eclipse console buffer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828255/how-do-i-increase-the-capacity-of-the-eclipse-output-console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, eclipse has a character limit on the console, but you can expand it or cancel the limit altogether.

In Eclipse's preferences, go to `Run/Debug`, then to `Console`. You see a checkbox "Limit console output". You can uncheck it, or you can change the `Console buffer size`.

I'm referring to Eclipse Luna.