# Why eclipse console not show log rang result

Tags: java, eclipse

**Why eclipse IDE console not show log rang result**

I try to print result on console but its show last 1000-1200 lines as result.

I try to execute following character combination program but cansole show only last few lines.

```
public class Combination_4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create an alphabet to work with
        char[] alphabet = new char[]  {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','~','!','@','#'};
        // Find all possible combinations of this alphabet in the string size of 3
        StringExcersise.possibleStrings(4, alphabet,"");
    }

} 
class StringExcersise {

    static int count=0;

    public static void possibleStrings(int maxLength, char[] alphabet, String curr) {

        // If the current string has reached it's maximum length
        if(curr.length() == maxLength) {
            count=count+1;

            System.out.println(curr);

        // Else add each letter from the alphabet to new strings and process these new strings again
        } else {
            for(int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
                String oldCurr = curr;
                curr += alphabet[i];
                possibleStrings(maxLength,alphabet,curr);
                curr = oldCurr;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried the answer here: [How do I increase the capacity of the Eclipse output console?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828255/how-do-i-increase-the-capacity-of-the-eclipse-output-console)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I increase the capacity of the Eclipse output console?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828255/how-do-i-increase-the-capacity-of-the-eclipse-output-console)

Answer (score 1):

Go to window  -> Preferences -> type console on search. -> click the console from run/debug.
you will get a screen given below.

[image: screent shot]

check the limit console output for make limit on console. uncheck it for no limit.