# Reading txt file with InputStream and Bufferreader, missing half the lines

Tags: java

I am testing a part of a bigger program so thats the reason if it looks a bit illogical to structure it this way.The code that I am using is fairly simple but I do not understand why the first half of the lines in the file are completely missing, they not being read at all.

```
public class Trying {

   public static String myReader(){
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader in = null;
        String str = null;
        try {
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream("c:/themap.txt");
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));


            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                buf.append(str);
                //buf.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

                System.out.println(str);
            }

            in.close();

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return buf.toString();
    }


public static void main(String[] args) {

    String fmap = myReader();

    //System.out.println(fmap);
```

As you can see I have a basic println in the function just to see what is happening and the first lines are not being shown at all. The rest of the file is being read as it is. Maybe it has to do with the file being 5000 lines long. Any help would be appreciated.

The file's lines look like this

```
o AE_Cube.014
v 4.996883 0.000000 -0.663325
v 4.996883 0.336000 -0.663325
v 4.490770 0.000000 -1.013470
v 4.490770 0.336000 -1.013470
v 4.990770 0.000000 -1.070477
v 4.990770 0.336000 -1.070477
v 4.589172 0.000000 -1.269103
```

They are all kind of like this. They don't change in the middle to some other format

The output I get is the same but with the first 1/3 of the file missing.

```
f 650//652 654//652 653//652
f 649//653 651//653 654//653
f 648//654 649//654 650//654
f 651//655 647//655 648//655
f 652//656 648//656 650//656
f 650//657 649//657 654//657
f 649//658 647//658 651//658
f 648//654 647//654 649//654
o DV_Cube.059
v -1.593174 0.150000 -2.197537
v -1.617969 0.150000 -2.297979
v -1.494583 0.150000 -2.229900
v -1.525588 0.150000 -2.324470
v -1.593001 0.000000 -2.199192
v -1.616714 0.000000 -2.297979
v -1.526114 0.000000 -2.324543
v -1.495018 0.000000 -2.229900
```

Comment: Can you show the first few lines of the input file?

Comment: And show the output you get.

Comment: Please edit your question instead

Comment: You should indent every line of the input with four spaces. Also is the input really double-spaced?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/veh2kGp.png

Comment: Please edit your question as requested.

Comment: If you want I'll upload the whole file to test with.

Comment: That is not necessary

Comment: The code you posted does not behave as described. It reads the entire file without any skipping. Either the input file is not as described, or the output isn't, or you aren't running this actual code. Are you perhaps running this in an IDE? which has truncated the beginning of the output? And which is it? Half the lines? or a third?

Comment: I am running this in Eclipse. Are you saying that the console is not displaying everything ? 

The first line that it outputs is from line 2391 from 5037 lines, so a little bit less than half is not being displayed.

Comment: That is the most obvious explanation. Try it at a console.

Comment: Bigger console? http://stackoverflow.com/q/2828255/589259

Comment: You are right it does read it from the start. I added a thread.sleep to slow it down to be sure. So the string is complete just the limitations of lines in the console is the problem. Thats a relief.

Comment: Yes. Its all there. Thank you very much for the help and patience.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the code works fine. My mistake is not disabling console limitations in Eclipse and it displaying incomplete string causing me to panic.

Thanks to EJP and  Maarten Bodewes.

Answer (score -1):

This should work.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {

public Test() {

}

public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{

    File file = new File("myFile");
    ArrayList <String> myText = new ArrayList<String>();
    StringBuilder myTextString = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String line;

        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            myText.add(line);
            myTextString.append(line + " ");
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(myText);
    System.out.println(myTextString);
}

}
```

In the example i show the way for both filling an array or just building a String with stringbuilder

Comment: "This should work" answers are generally poor answers. You need to explain a little bit why this code is answering the question and what is the problem being addressed here. No doubt that this should work for you, but what if it doesn't work for everyone?