# Eclipse is not executing all answer(numbers from 901000000 to 999999999)

Tags: java, numbers

Eclipse is not executing all answer(numbers from 901000000 to 999999999)
i can get only like 2000 or 3000 numbers

```
long a;
for (a=901000000; a<=999999999; a++) 
    System.out.println(a);
```

Comment: Console usually isn't configured to hold all lines, but only most recent N lines which is why you may not see previous ones.

Comment: I would look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828255/how-do-i-increase-the-capacity-of-the-eclipse-output-console

Comment: It may be worth clarifying how you are determining "not executing" - is this just based on what you see in the output after execution or are you looking at the execution in debug mode or watching the console as it generates things? It'd help to clarify this in your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to uncheck the console output limit

[image: You need to unchecked the cosole output limit]