# How to print the values of an array object on a new line each

Tags: java, arrays, object

I know how to print on a new line using an ArrayList but what about using a standard Array like the one shown below?

```java
public class School {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student[] studentList = new Student[10];
    //postGraduate Student #1
    myDate completionDate = new myDate(6, 10, 2019);
    Address address = new Address(199, "Hurrican road", 2568, "Australia");
    studentList[0] = new postGraduate("Greg", 6789, address, 31272890, 4565000, completionDate, "Computer Science");
    System.out.println("***Postgraduate Students***");
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
      System.out.println(studentList[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Esentinally i want the elements of each new student index("Greg", 6789, address, 31272890, 4565000, completionDate, "Computer Science") to be on a new line so it looks more tidy. Cheers

Comment: What are the current and expected outputs?

Comment: @lealceldeiro current is it prints on one line, expected i stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

for loop condition, seems to be the issue.

Please check m.antkowicz answer.

I would suggest you to use `foreach` loop, to get rid of such errors

```
for(Student student: studentList) {
   System.out.println(student);
}
```

If you are using Java-8, use declarative style to enhance the readability of your code

```
Arrays.stream (studentList).forEach (System.out::println);
```

In both cases, make sure `toString` is overridden for Student.

NOTE: If you are using eclipse and array size is on the larger size, make sure you have sufficient console buffer [How do I increase the capacity of the Eclipse output console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828255/how-do-i-increase-the-capacity-of-the-eclipse-output-console?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

To print on a new line try putting an empty `System.out.println()` line. That way, for each iteration through the loop it will go on a new line.

`for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    System.out.print(studentList[i]);
    System.out.println(" ");
}`

Answer (score -1):

Your code is okay but you are not iterating through the whole `studentList` array.

If your `studentList` array length is `10`, you want your loop to iterate from `0` to `9`, not from `0` to `0` (this is what your code is doing).

To avoid hardcoding the size of `studentList` array, you can get its size using `studentlist.length`.

Hence, you can modify your loop conditions as shown below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < studentList.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(studentList[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

in java there is a way to get length of array or array list "`arrayname.length`"

```
for (int i = 0; i < studentList.length ; i++) {
  System.out.println(studentList[i]);
}
```

Comment: Please add more information for the OP to understand.