# How can I print a number with a high quantity of decimals in the console?

Tags: java, eclipse, bigdecimal, eulers-number

It seems a very basic question, but I have been having this problem for a while.

I am coding a program in Eclipse IDE which calculates a high quantity of decimals of the Euler's number, and it works fine with quantities like 100, 400, 1000...

But when I want to print more than 1500 decimals, this is the output that I get:

[image]

It only prints "2.", I thought that was a problem of the algorithm, so, to check if my code was correct, I stored the output in the clipboard to see the result number, and it was calculating more than 1500 decimals without any error.

Anybody knows how can I print the number in the console without having this mistake?

Also I leave the code here to provide more details:

```java
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.math.*;

import javax.tools.Tool;

public class eulersNumberCalculation {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    // E NUMBER

    BigDecimal eNumber = new BigDecimal("0"), precision = new BigDecimal("1500");

    for (BigDecimal i = BigDecimal.valueOf(0); i.compareTo(precision) <= 0; i = i.add(BigDecimal.ONE)) {
        BigDecimal res = BigDecimal.ONE.divide(factorial(i), new MathContext(100, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
        eNumber = eNumber.add(res);
    }

    System.out.print(eNumber.toString());
}

public static BigDecimal factorial(BigDecimal n) {
    if (n.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0) {
        return BigDecimal.ONE;
    } else {
        BigDecimal b = n;
        b = b.subtract(BigDecimal.ONE);
        BigDecimal resultado = n;

        for (BigDecimal i = n; i.compareTo(new BigDecimal("1")) > 0; i = i.subtract(BigDecimal.ONE)) {
            resultado = resultado.multiply(b);
            b = b.subtract(new BigDecimal("1"));
        }
        return resultado;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I tested the code on a online compiler and it works fine. It also prints it fine.

Comment: Works fine in VScode also!!!

Comment: Yes, but in Eclipse IDE it doesn't work, maybe is a problem of the console in Eclipse, or the version that I am using

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828255/how-do-i-increase-the-capacity-of-the-eclipse-output-console/2828293

Comment: I have already unchecked the "Limit Console Output" option, it keeps printing only '2.'

Comment: I tested the code on an online eclipse ide. It works fine there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck the console limit (or set to an appropriate number)  and set the fixed width value.

[image]

Comment: Solved, it was the fixed width console that it was deactivated, thank you