# Eclipse - how to give the Java Console unlimited length (in # lines)

Tags: java, eclipse, console

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [adjusting eclipse console size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600653/adjusting-eclipse-console-size)

I am trying to debug an app that I have set up to run locally and it is writing all of its `System.out.println()` statements to the Java Console in Eclipse.

The problem is, it's spitting out 10s of thousands of lines, and by the time the app finishes processing and shuts down, I can only see the last ~25% of sysout statements.

Am I doomed? Or is there a setting in Eclipse that lets me un-restrict the number of lines the Console keeps in memory or keeps viewable.

And, if this isn't possible, is there a way to redirect output to a file or something that *can* hold 40,000+ lines of output?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Go to  Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > Console there's a checkbox "Limit console output" and a textfield for entering the buffer size of the console.

Just try this out. It works for me but my code is outputting not more than 1000 lines .