# JavaFX: How to see exception on the console

Tags: java, exception, javafx, console

I execute a JavaFX application from the Eclipse (Luna). The application throws an exception during loading FXML or initializing of the application. I see the exception (red lines) on the console pane in Eclipse, but I can see it 1 second only: after the application window appears the console output is clear. Is it possible to prevent console clearing?

Comment: I've never had this problem. Could you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Maybe the output is truncated by the limit. See here for config Eclipse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945882/eclipse-how-to-give-the-java-console-unlimited-length-in-lines

Comment: No, it is not problem of limitation. Settings is 80000 (it is more than enough). Seems like two threads writes into console output and second clear all previous output.

Comment: You can try to run it in command-line, to see the exception.

Comment: Is there another Java process running from eclipse? That might cause Eclipse to switch to the console display for that process when your JavaFX application terminates.